# Calculate a distance in for racing game in python

Tags: python, pygame

Implementing a racing game in python and spyral and I'm having trouble keeping track of distance. I have a speed, raceDistance, currentDistance currentTim ect... In the update function I am setting currentDistance = speed * currentTime. This seems to work but I'm trying to implement a way to increase the speed when questions are answer correctly. If I just increase the speed, currentDist is calculated as if it was going the new speed the entire race.

```
self.speed = 10    
self.raceDistance = 100

def update(self): 
    self.tempTime = time.time() - timeStart 
    self.currentDistance = self.tempTime * self.speed      
    self.timeText.update("Current Time: %.2f" % self.tempTime) 

    if(self.currentDistance >= self.raceDistance):
        global Game_music
        Game_music.stop()
        finishTime = time.time() - timeStart                      
        print "Finish Time = %.2f" % finishTime            
        self.goToMenu()
```

Can view all the code here:
https://github.com/mreist/Team-Titan/blob/MaxxTesting/SpeedSolver/game/Race.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're having issues calcuating your speed is because of the following:

```
self.currentDistance = self.tempTime * self.speed
```

every time you call the function, you're resetting the self.currentDistance, instead of adding to it.

The easiest way to update your distance is to add to the current distance at every time point.

for example:

```
class Whatever(object):
    def get_new_distance(self, old_distance, delta_time, rate):
        delta_distance = delta_time * rate
        new_distance = old_distance + delta_distance
        return new_distance

    def update(self):
       self.delta_time = time.time() - self.last_time_call
       self.last_time_call = time.time() #for use in the next update

       self.current_distance = \
           self.get_new_distance(self.current_distance, self.delta_time,\
           self.rate)
```